# Clustering key restriction for "IN" condition in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have table in cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE pica_pictures (
  p int,
  g text,
  id text,
  a int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((p), g, id)
)
```

Then I try select data with query:

```
cqlsh> select * from picapica_realty.pica_pictures where p = 1 and g in ('1', '2');
Bad Request: Clustering column "g" cannot be restricted by an IN relation
```

I can't find cause of this behavior.

Comment: That's valid in Cassandra 2.2, unless a column of collection type is selected by the query.

Comment: I found doc describing IN keyword [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useQueryIN.html) . According link it should work. `A single clustering column can be defined if all preceding columns are defined for either equality or group inclusion.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a restriction due to your version of Cassandra.  As Cedric noted, it works for him in 2.2 (or rather, didn't error-out).

However, as I read your question I recalled a slide from a presentation that I gave at Cassandra Day Chicago 2015.  From [CQL: This is not the SQL you are looking for](http://www.slideshare.net/aploetz/cql-this-is-not-the-sql-you-are-loooking-for), silde #15:

> **IN**
>
> - Can only operate on the last partition key and/or the last clustering key.

At the time (April 2015) the most-current version of Cassandra was either 2.1.4 or 2.1.5.

As it stands (with Cassandra 2.1) you'll either need to adjust your primary key definition to `PRIMARY KEY ((p), g)`, or adjust your WHERE clause to something like `where p = 1 and g = 1 and id in ('id1', 'id2');`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that restriction, thanks for the link. What do you mean by "rather"? It's still illegal but with not error message?

Comment: @CedricH. I mean to say that while your answer makes a good point, a query that returns `0 rows` may not be the best indicator that something "works."

Answer (score 1):

This does word with Cassandra 2.2.

```
cqlsh:ks> CREATE TABLE pica_pictures (
          ...   p int,
          ...   g text,
          ...   id text,
          ...   a int,
          ...   PRIMARY KEY ((p), g, id)
          ... );
cqlsh:ks> select * from pica_pictures where p = 1 and g in ('1', '2');

 p | g | id | a
---+---+----+---

(0 rows)
```

As your link describes this works because the the preceding columns are defined for equality and none of the queried columns are of a collection type.